# Access innertext of 2nd TR's 2nd TD with html agility pack?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

i want to access in c#, innertext of 2nd TR's 2nd TD, i.e. john paul and 30 with html agility pack?

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableClass">
    <form name="form1" action="goto.php" method="post">
        <tr>

            <td height="35" colspan="2" class="tdClass"
                style="padding-top:5px "><img
                src="./include/gif/grey-sub-header-ex-customer.gif"
                alt="details" width="162" height="20" /></td>
            <td valign="top" class="tdClass">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="trRow">
            <td width="190" class="tdDataRow">name:</td>
            <td class="tdDataName">john paul</td>
            <td class="whiteClass">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="trRow">
            <td width="190" class="tdDataRow">age:</td>
            <td class="tdDataName">30</td>
            <td class="whiteClass">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Take a look at the code, although it would be good to paste the entire HTML code, or at least close `<form>` and `<table>` tags. `<table>` is supposed to be inside `<form>`...

Answer (score 5):

Once you have the `HtmlDocument` loaded (either by `new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.site.com")` or by `doc.Load(...)`) you can do:

```
//Get 2nds <td> tags inside all tr class of that table
var tds = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='tableClass']/tr[@class='trRow']/td[2]");
foreach (var td in tds) {
    Console.WriteLine(td.InnerText);
}
```

**Edit:**
I edited the code because `<tr>` tags weren't inside `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

add attribute `runat="server"` to the td you want to access

```
        <td id="tdname" runat="server" class="tdDataName">john paul</td>
```

then u can directly access the inner text as

```
 string name=tdname.InnerText;      //where tdname is the id of td
```